# regexp_replace to extract from string containing -

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

Pulling my hair with this. Any help or direction would be very much appreciated.

Column values:

```
u-165645,c-934846,f-598715,one, appple
c-997556.41,test,u-4404932, testing,two
```

Trying to extract values that begins with 'c-'.
From above examples, the extracted would be:

```
934846
997556.41
```

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: How many times in a column could the value you are after occur? At least once? Zero or more?  Since you mention column, is this data stored in a database?  More info is needed for an accurate answer.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: vmp: language is oracle sql. thanks!

Comment: Gary_w: c-1234 can occur only once but can occur anywhere in the string, delimited by a comma.  thanks!

Comment: Gary_w: c-1234 can occur only once but can occur anywhere in the string, delimited by a comma.  for example, if applied to u-16445,c-194846.41,f-99899,one the result should be 194846.41. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.  The `WITH` clause just sets up your data using a Common Table Expression (CTE).  The regular expression uses a captured group to return what follows the "c-" when followed by a comma or the end of the line, so it does not matter where in the string the pattern occurs.

```
WITH tbl(ID, DATA) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'u-165645,c-934846,f-598715,one, appple' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'c-997556.41,test,u-4404932, testing,two' FROM dual
)
SELECT ID,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, 'c-(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) c_element
FROM tbl;


        ID C_ELEMENT                              
---------- ---------------------------------------
         1 934846                                 
         2 997556.41                              

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Gary_W. I am going to play with your solution to understand how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

You capture:

```
c-([*]*)
```

and replace by

```
\1
```

I don't know which language or editor you are using... I've tried this on Notepad++

Comment: when applied to u-16445,c-194846.41,f-99899,one the result is u-16445,194846.41,f-99899,one but it should be just 194846.41.  thank you!